# Unity Leap Motion Error Message "INPUT AXIS NOT SET UP"

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, leap-motion

I'm currently doing my first VR project with Leap Motion, HTC Vive and Unity.
When I create a new project and add the LeapRig, everything is just fine, but after adding the Interaction Manager as a child of LeapRig, I get the following error message, which gets repeated multiple times a second:

```
INPUT AXIS NOT SET UP.  Go to your Input Manager and add a definition for  on the 9th Joystick Axis.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionXRController:fixedUpdateGraspButtonState(Boolean) (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionXRController.cs:733)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionXRController:fixedUpdateGraspingState() (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionXRController.cs:706)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionController:fixedUpdateGrasping() (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionController.cs:1783)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionController:Leap.Unity.Interaction.IInternalInteractionController.FixedUpdateController() (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionController.cs:259)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionManager:fixedUpdateInteractionControllers() (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionManager.cs:372)
Leap.Unity.Interaction.InteractionManager:FixedUpdate() (at Assets/LeapMotion/Modules/InteractionEngine/Scripts/InteractionManager.cs:299)
```

Has anyone an idea why this happens and how to fix it?
I already worked with the interaction manager, but suddenly this error message occured.
I can run my program just fine too, but the error bothers me anyway and makes it difficult to use the console properly.

Greetings from Germany

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Interaction Engine docs:

> If you intend to use the Interaction Engine with Oculus Touch or Vive
>   controllers, you'll need to configure your project's input settings
>   before you'll be able to use the controllers to grasp objects. Input
>   settings are project settings that cannot be changed by imported
>   packages, which is why we can't configure these input settings for
>   you. You can skip this section if you are only interested in using
>   Leap hands with the Interaction Engine.
>
> Go to your Input Manager (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input) and set
>   up the joystick axes you'd like to use for left-hand and right-hand
>   grasps. (Controller triggers are still referred to as 'joysticks' in
>   Unity's parlance.) Then make sure each InteractionXRController has its
>   grasping axis set to the corresponding axis you set up. The default
>   prefabs for left and right InteractionXRControllers will look for axes
>   named LeftXRTriggerAxis and RightXRTriggerAxis, respectively.
>
> Helpful diagrams and axis labels can be found in Unity's
>   documentation.